# Jasmine afterAll not called when error is thrown

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am using Jasmine 2.3.1.  The following spec execution results in the afterAll method not being called:

```
var http = require('http');

describe("simple server tests:", function() {

    afterAll(function(done) {
        console.log('after all');
    });

    it("throws an error because server is not running", function(done) {
        http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080", function(res) {
            res.on('data', function(data) {
                done();
            });
        });
    });   
});
```

The console shows:

```
[23:25:24] Starting 'test'...
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
```

My expectation would be that the afterAll is called, irrespective of the error thrown in the test method.  I really don't want to put a try catch around my tests.  Please let me know if this is an issue with Jasmine or my usage of Jasmine.

Answer (score 1):

`afterAll` is called when all of the specs have been completed, but it your situation server is not running and as a result `done()` is never called. If you are testing that the server is not running, I would suggest to add an error handler for the request and execute `done()` inside it:

```
var http = require('http');

describe("simple server tests:", function() {

    afterAll(function(done) {
        console.log('after all');
        done(); // do not forget to execute done if you use it
    });

    it("throws an error because server is not running", function(done) {

        http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080", function(res) {
            res.on('data', function(data) {
                // never called
            })
        }).on('error', function(e) {
            console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
            done(); // finish async test
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: if done isn't called then I would expect a timeout and the afterall method to be called. The problem I have it that any test could fail with a syntax error or unexpected error. And in these cases afterall is not called. I would expect afterall to be called in all cases even when an error is thrown.

Comment: It exits with an exception because of the asynchronous behavior of a tested unit. Jasmine catches sync exceptions, but not async, because they are out if it's scope. You can try even `setTimeout(function () { a = b; }, 500);` and get a `ReferenceError` with a test suite exiting. Nothing catches this exception, therefore the entire suite goes down. Evidently if suite is down there is no way `afterAll` could be called. I has to be a [known issue](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/529)

Comment: Maybe this module could help you - [jasmine-async-errors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-async-errors).

Comment: I think this is a known issue.  I have switched to mocha which handles this correctly.  I tried the async errors (wrapping the it method) but it didn't work.  If Jasmine added support for async tests with done() I would have hoped they would be able to handle errors too.